# async function in mocha

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mocha.js, assert

Receiving issues on trying to assert an error message for the test case

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error
at Context.it (test\index.js:24:80)
```

```
if (configVms.rts) {
describe('Real Time Services', () => {
    for(let rtsConfig of configVms["rts"].rtsConfig) {
        it(`Real Time Services endpoints for guid ${rtsConfig.resourceId} on ${rtsConfig.platformType} platform`, async () => {
            expect(async () => await realTimeServices.main(rtsConfig)).to.throw('Host rejected');
        });
    }});
}
```

Comment: Try expect(await realTimeServices.main(rtsConfig)).to.throw('Host rejected');

Answer (score 2):

`to.throw` is applicable only to synchronous functions. 
In your case I would recommend to add `chai-as-promised` plugin and change test:

```js
if (configVms.rts) {
describe('Real Time Services', () => {
    for(let rtsConfig of configVms["rts"].rtsConfig) {
        it(`Real Time Services endpoints for guid ${rtsConfig.resourceId} on ${rtsConfig.platformType} platform`, async () => {
            await expect(realTimeServices.main(rtsConfig)).to.be.rejectedWith('Host rejected');
        });
    }});
}
```